# Is there a difference between 「qrコード 作成」 and 「qrコード作成」?

Tags: business-japanese

It is a very basic question but I'm trying to optimize search keywords of my web page and I don't know a space character(qrコード 作成 vs qrコード作成) makes any difference.

Comment: This is not the place for web development questions, try https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/seo.

Comment: Belongs on [webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/seo](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/seo). Voting to close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Japanese doesn't use spaces, so 「qrコード作成」 should be fine.